# What does the sum of a Maclaurin/Taylor Series represent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $π - \frac{π^3}{3!} + \frac{π^7}{7!} $

I understand that the series above is an expansion of $\sin x$ but I don't understand why the sum of the series above is equal to $\sin π$.

Is the sum of a series equivalent to the actual value of $f(x)$?

Comment: Under certain assumptions, yes, the Taylor series converges to $f(x)$. This is proved in real analysis books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In blue, the sine. The other curves are Taylor polynomials of increasing order.

[image]

Though you can't see it on the plot, none of the curves exactly coincide (except at $x=0$), but they are very close on increasing ranges.

As the series for the sine converges for all $x$, with an "infinite" number of terms, the polynomial truly computes the sine function (provided that the computation is made with perfect precision). With a finite number of terms, the approximation is better and better when you get closer to $x=0$.

On the second plot, you see the remainders (i.e. the approximation error).

[image]

Comment: +1 : very nice.

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series is:

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} -\frac{x^7}{7!} + \ldots $$

There are infinitely many terms on the RHS and we only have equality after adding up all infinitely many of them.

This is true for the Taylor series of any function $f(x)$ that has all derivatives $f'(x), f''(x), f'''(x), \ldots$ well defined.

In particularly for $x=\pi$ we have

$$\sin(\pi) = \pi - \frac{\pi^3}{3!} + \frac{\pi^5}{5!} -\frac{\pi^7}{7!} + \ldots $$

We need to add all the terms on the RHS. Not just the first three terms as you have written. Another way to check is that $\sin(\pi) =0$ and $ \pi - \frac{\pi^3}{3!} + \frac{\pi^5}{5!} \simeq 0.524$. So the two things cannot equal each other.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series at infinity, the "full sum", which only exists for a smooth function, is indeed equal to the function itself. In fact, it is often used as a way to define the function formally; like is done for the exponential of matrices.

A partial sum of a Taylor series up to a rank $n$ is the best polynomial approximation of degree $n$ around the given point.